# Choosing appropriate WorkingPrecision when solving numerical system of equations

Tags: equation-solving, linear-algebra

Consider a linear system of equations, which is conveniently written as `A.x=y`. The matrix `A` has dimensions `500x500`, while `x` and `y` are of course `500` dimensional vectors. Matrix `A` and vector `y` contain numerical (float) numbers that in principle can be generated with arbitrary precision. Analytically, it is expected that `x` will contain mostly zeros and a couple of integers of magnitude `<10`. It turns out that a generic matrix `A`, in the particular problem at hand, has condition number such that:

```
Log10[LinearAlgebra`MatrixConditionNumber[A]]
```

> 27.053931

which means that while `x` is being determined, around `27` digits of precision are expected to be lost purely due to the properties of matrix A (even before the loss due to rounding errors etc). Considering the above, what starting precision for entries of matrix `A` and vector `y` should I shoot for in order to unambiguously determine vector `x` while spending as little calculation time as possible? Is there any estimate one can make apart from doing several experimental trial and error calculations?

**EDIT**

I have been asked where the matrix `A` comes from. It's origin is in Physics. Here is how it is constructed. First we generate `n=6` light-like Minkowski-space momenta which add up to zero:

```
n = 6; precis = 200; max = 1;
Do[
  Subscript[p, i, 1] = RandomReal[{-max, max}, WorkingPrecision -> precis];
  Subscript[p, i, 2] = RandomReal[{-max, max}, WorkingPrecision -> precis];
  Subscript[p, i, 3] = RandomReal[{-max, max}, WorkingPrecision -> precis];
  Subscript[p, i, 0] = (-1)^RandomInteger[{0, 1}] Sqrt[Subscript[p, i, 1]^2 + Subscript[p, i, 2]^2 + Subscript[p, i, 3]^2];
, {i, 1, n - 2}];
Subscript[p, n - 1, 2] = -Sum[Subscript[p, i, 2], {i, 1, n - 2}];
Subscript[p, n - 1, 3] = -Sum[Subscript[p, i, 3], {i, 1, n - 2}];
Subscript[p, n, 2] = 0; Subscript[p, n, 3] = 0;
AA = Sum[Subscript[p, i, 0], {i, 1, n - 2}];
BB = Sum[Subscript[p, i, 1], {i, 1, n - 2}];
DD = Subscript[p, n - 1, 2]^2 + Subscript[p, n - 1, 3]^2;
Subscript[p, n, 0] = (-AA^2 + BB^2 + DD)/(2 (AA + BB));
Subscript[p, n, 1] = -((-AA^2 + BB^2 + DD)/(2 (AA + BB)));
Subscript[p, n - 1, 0] = -(((AA + BB)^2 + DD)/(2 (AA + BB)));
Subscript[p, n - 1, 1] = (-(AA + BB)^2 + DD)/(2 (AA + BB));
Table[Sum[Subscript[p, i, j], {i, 1, n}], {j, 0, 3}]
Table[Subscript[p, i, 0]^2 - (Subscript[p, i, 1]^2 + Subscript[p, i, 2]^2 + Subscript[p, i, 3]^2), {i, 1, n}]
pq[x_, y_] := Subscript[p, x, 0] Subscript[p, y, 0] - (Subscript[p, x, 1] Subscript[p, y, 1] + Subscript[p, x, 2] Subscript[p, y, 2] + Subscript[p, x, 3] Subscript[p, y, 3]);
```

As the output from the two tables demonstrates, the light-like and add-up-to-zero constraints are properly satisfied. Function `pq[x,y]` gives the inner product over Minkowski space. Next, define a function that when called will change the momenta slightly but maintain the conditions:

```
ChangeMomentaSlightly[] := Module[{},
  max = 1/10000;
  Do[
   Subscript[p, i, 1] = RandomReal[{Subscript[p, i, 1] - max, Subscript[p, i, 1] + max}, WorkingPrecision -> precis];
   Subscript[p, i, 2] = RandomReal[{Subscript[p, i, 2] - max, Subscript[p, i, 2] + max}, WorkingPrecision -> precis];
   Subscript[p, i, 3] = RandomReal[{Subscript[p, i, 3] - max, Subscript[p, i, 3] + max}, WorkingPrecision -> precis];
   Subscript[p, i, 0] = Sign[Subscript[p, i, 0]] Sqrt[Subscript[p, i, 1]^2 + Subscript[p, i, 2]^2 + Subscript[p, i, 3]^2];
   , {i, 1, n - 2}];
  Subscript[p, n - 1, 2] = -Sum[Subscript[p, i, 2], {i, 1, n - 2}];
  Subscript[p, n - 1, 3] = -Sum[Subscript[p, i, 3], {i, 1, n - 2}];
  Subscript[p, n, 2] = 0; Subscript[p, n, 3] = 0;
  AA = Sum[Subscript[p, i, 0], {i, 1, n - 2}];
  BB = Sum[Subscript[p, i, 1], {i, 1, n - 2}];
  DD = Subscript[p, n - 1, 2]^2 + Subscript[p, n - 1, 3]^2;
  Subscript[p, n, 0] = (-AA^2 + BB^2 + DD)/(2 (AA + BB));
  Subscript[p, n, 1] = -((-AA^2 + BB^2 + DD)/(2 (AA + BB)));
  Subscript[p, n - 1, 0] = -(((AA + BB)^2 + DD)/(2 (AA + BB)));
  Subscript[p, n - 1, 1] = (-(AA + BB)^2 + DD)/(2 (AA + BB));]
```

Now, using `s[Subscript[k, x] + Subscript[k, y]]` as an analytic representation for `pq[x,y]` (and equivalently `pq[y,x]`) we can construct one particular set of linearly independent inner products among the `n` vectors (this gives `9` different elements):

```
mySet = DeleteCases[ DeleteCases[Table[s[Subscript[k, x] + Subscript[k, y]], {x, 2, n}, {y, 2,n}] /. s[2 Subscript[k, _]] -> 0 // Flatten //DeleteDuplicates, 0], s[Subscript[k, 2] + Subscript[k, 3]]];
```

Then create a table of all possible unique multiplications of four elements in `mySet` with each other (this gives `495` different elements):

```
myTab = Table[ mySet[[i]] mySet[[j]] mySet[[q]] mySet[[w]], {i, 1, 9}, {j, 1, 9}, {q, 1, 9}, {w, 1, 9}] // Flatten // DeleteDuplicates;
```

For the sake of discussion, let's create a sample vector `y` which we can experiment with:

```
rndm[x_, y_] := RandomInteger[{x, y}];
sampleY = Sum[rndm[0, 1] rndm[1, 10] myTab[[rndm[1, 495]]], {i, 1, rndm[1, 495]}];
```

Finally, numerical matrix `A` is created as:

```
A = DiagonalMatrix[Range[495]];
y = Table[0, {i, 1, 495}];
Do[ChangeMomentaSlightly[];
 y[[i]] = sampleY /. s[Subscript[k, x_] + Subscript[k, y_]] :> pq[x, y];
 Do[A[[i, j]] = myTab[[j]] /. s[Subscript[k, x_] + Subscript[k, y_]] :> pq[x, y];, {j, 1, 495}];
, {i, 1, 495}]
```

The actual vector `y` is not known analytically and there is a certain lengthy calculation that can be used to obtain it numerically. The whole point of the above procedure is to fix the coefficients in front of a complete set of functions in order to determine what `y` is analytically. The sample data above seems to work out fine at a working precision of `200`:

```
fun = LinearSolve[A];
fun[y] // Chop // Rationalize
```

However, it would be nice to be able to estimate the sweet spot for working precision in order to automate the process and spend as little computation time as possible on each `A` and `y`.

Comment: Apart from sparsity, is there any other structure in your matrix? Would you mind telling where it came from?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too localized; i.e, it applies only to the local situation and needs of its poster and answers will not benefit others.